# Relationship between conditional probability and correlation

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, correlation

Is there a relationship between the conditional probability between two events and the correlation between them? For example, is it more likely there is a positive or negative correlation if the conditional probability reaches a certain point?

Comment: What's "the conditional probability between two events"?

Comment: P(A | B) = the probability of A, given B

Comment: The correlation between $A$ and $B$ is symmetric in $A$ and $B$, whereas $P(B\mid A)\ne P(A\mid B)$, so it makes little sense to call one of the two "the conditional probability between two events". What would you call the other one then?

Answer (score 4):

By the correlation between two events $A$ and $B$, I presume you mean the Pearson correlation coefficient between their indicator random variables $I_A$ and $I_B$.  We have

$$ \text{Cov}(I_A, I_B) = \mathbb E[I_A I_B] - \mathbb E[I_A] \mathbb E[I_B] = \mathbb P(A \cap B) - \mathbb P(A) \mathbb P(B) = \mathbb P(A) \mathbb P(A^c) (\mathbb P(B \mid A) - \mathbb P(B \mid A^c)) $$
$$ \sigma(I_A) = \sqrt{\mathbb P(A) \mathbb P(A^c)}$$
and similarly for $\sigma(I_B)$, so the Pearson correlation coefficient is
$$ r = \sqrt{\frac{\mathbb P(A) \mathbb P(A^c)}{\mathbb P(B) \mathbb P(B^c)}} (\mathbb P(B\mid A) - \mathbb P(B \mid A^c))$$

In particular, $r > 0$ iff $0 < \mathbb P(A) < 1$ and $\mathbb P(B \mid A) > \mathbb P(B \mid A^c)$.

Comment: So, is it correct then to say that P(B | A) must be greater than 0.5 in order for r > 0?

Comment: No, it is not.  $P(B \mid A)$ could be as small as you want, as long as it's greater than $P(B \mid A^c)$.